# How to cast a column datatype if all its elements are null?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I have some attributes in my database, starting from this big dataset I have to split it into different parquet files: 1 per day.

Every parquet file must have the same datatype for its column, however often happens that a single day has all the record Null for a specific attribute, therefore the datatype of the column appears to be null, while when there is at least one valid record the datatype has its correct type. It is important for my application that every parquet file will have the same datatype. How can i manage to obtain this result?

In particular there are 4 situations:

1. Datetime column
2. Integer column
3. String column
4. Float column

I will copy paste column schema for 2 parquets file in order to give an example.
These are 2 parquets, uploaded on Pandas, for 2 different days:

```
         NEW1                                             NEW2                               NEW3 
0   {"id":{"VAR1": 1}}      {"AA":{"VAR2": 2, "ACTUAL_END": "2002-03-01T13:00:00Z"}}      {"TS": 6}
1   {"id":{"VAR1": 2}}      {"AA":{"VAR2": 4, "ACTUAL_END": "2002-03-01T13:00:00Z"}}      {"TS":12}
2   {"id":{"VAR1": 3}}      {"AA":{"VAR2": 6, "ACTUAL_END": None}}                        {"TS":18}
3   {"id":{"VAR1": 4}}      {"AA":{"VAR2": 8, "ACTUAL_END": None}}                        {"TS":24}
4   {"id":{"VAR1": 5}}      {"AA":{"VAR2":10, "ACTUAL_END": "2002-03-01T13:00:00Z"}}      {"TS":30}
5   {"id":{"VAR1": 6}}      {"AA":{"VAR2":12, "ACTUAL_END": "2002-03-01T13:00:00Z"}}      {"TS":36}
```

```
         NEW1                                             NEW2             NEW3 
0   {"id":{"VAR1": 1}}      {"AA":{"VAR2": 2, "ACTUAL_END": None}}      {"TS": 6}
1   {"id":{"VAR1": 2}}      {"AA":{"VAR2": 4, "ACTUAL_END": None}}      {"TS":12}
2   {"id":{"VAR1": 3}}      {"AA":{"VAR2": 6, "ACTUAL_END": None}}      {"TS":18}
3   {"id":{"VAR1": 4}}      {"AA":{"VAR2": 8, "ACTUAL_END": None}}      {"TS":24}
4   {"id":{"VAR1": 5}}      {"AA":{"VAR2":10, "ACTUAL_END": None}}      {"TS":30}
5   {"id":{"VAR1": 6}}      {"AA":{"VAR2":12, "ACTUAL_END": None}}      {"TS":36}
```

this is the result when i try to examine my files using

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
pfile = pq.read_table("my_transformed.parquet")
print("Schema: {}".format(pfile.schema))
```

First case, the one with at least one valid record for each attribute

> Schema: _myschema: struct<crm: struct<task: struct<ACTIVITY_STATUS:
> string, CREATED_ON: string, TASK_ID: string, crmInfo: struct<CAMPAGNA:
> string, ID_OPERATORE: string>, esitoInfo: struct<NEGATIVE_RESULTS:
> string, RESULTS: string>, timeInfo: struct<**ACTUAL_END: string**>>

Second case, the one with all null dates (ACTUAL_END). Also note that despite pyarrow interpreting these as "string", ACTUAL_END is a datetime in ISO 8601.

> Schema: _myschema: struct<crm: struct<task: struct<ACTIVITY_STATUS:
> string, CREATED_ON: string, TASK_ID: string, crmInfo: struct<CAMPAGNA:
> string, ID_OPERATORE: string>, esitoInfo: struct<NEGATIVE_RESULTS:
> string, RESULTS: string>, timeInfo: struct<**ACTUAL_END: null**>>

Comment: How are you creating the table that you eventually save to a parquet file?  Generally there should be a way to specify the schema when you create the table so it doesn't have to guess.

Comment: I’m reading a csv, I split it iterating over dates, then I save each chunk as parquet file. Once a chunk is created if all its records in a column are null the column type is null. Tomorrow i will update my example so you can create your own pandas dataframe just copypasting it into ‘pd.DataFrame.from_dict()’ and check your own the datatypes. I will update you

Comment: When converting the chunk to pyarrow / writing it to parquet, you should be able to specify the schema to use.